# Web scraping ul li tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the ul & li tags for capterra product pages. The information I want to get and store in separate variables is the "located in 'country," "the url address," and the product features.

Currently, I only know how to print the text for everything in the ul & li, not something specific.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import requests

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.capterra.com/p/81310/AMCS/")

companyProfile = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

url = companyProfile.find("ul", class_="nb-type-md nb-list-undecorated undefined").text

features = companyProfile.find("div", class_="nb-col-count-1 sm:nb-col-count-2 md:nb-col-count-3 nb-col-gap-xl nb-my-0 nb-mx-auto").text 

print(url)
print(features)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
AMCSLocated in United StatesFounded in 2004http://www.amcsgroup.com/
Billing & InvoicingBrokerage ManagementBuy / Sell TicketingContainer ManagementCustomer AccountsCustomer DatabaseDispatch ManagementElectronics RecyclingEquipment TrackingFingerprint ScanningID ScanningIntegrated CamerasInventory ManagementInventory TrackingLogistics Management
```

How do I get only the url and the country, and how do I get the features neatly?

---

I was able to get the URL and the location by:

```
url = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "//*[starts-with(., 'http')]").text

location = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "//*[starts-with(., 'Located in')]").text
```

Still looking for a solution for the features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will pull  all the text nodes value separately from `ul > li` tags

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.find_all('ul',class_="nb-type-md nb-list-undecorated undefined"):
    name = li.select_one('[class="nb-type-md nb-list-undecorated undefined"] li:nth-child(1) > span').get_text()
    location = li.select_one('[class="nb-type-md nb-list-undecorated undefined"] li:nth-child(2) > span').get_text()
    year = li.select_one('[class="nb-type-md nb-list-undecorated undefined"] li:nth-child(3) > span').get_text()
    link = li.select_one('[class="nb-type-md nb-list-undecorated undefined"] li:nth-child(4) > span').get_text()

    print(name)
    print(location)
    print(year)
    print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
AMCS
Located in United States 
Founded in 2004
http://www.amcsgroup.com/
```

Update:

```
li=[x.get_text() for x in soup.select('[class="nb-type-md nb-list-undecorated undefined"] li span')]
print(li)
```

**Output:**

```
['AMCS', 'Located in United States', 'Founded in 2004', 'http://www.amcsgroup.com/']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close and better than I could ever do. There is one issue though, on other product pages (example: https://www.capterra.com/p/135137/Waste-Logics/) the link appears in the child(3). Is there a way to have it find the link without depending on the child location? Thank you.

Comment: @BQuist I've edited which will over  come  the above restriction you have mentioned.

Comment: This is close, and thanks! How do we only get the "located in United States" and "http://www.amcsgroup.com/" using separate variables?